# French Work Permit has expired and appointment to get récépissé is almost two months away

Tags: france, resident-permit, eu

My situation is as follows: I have been resident in France for almost five years now, first on a student visa and then on a work permit. A few months ago as the date of expiry of my work permit approached, I followed procedure on the Prefects website and sent in my application for a new work permit. There was no response for almost six weeks and then ironically the day my work permit expired I got a letter from the Prefect informing me that my appointment to collect my "récépissé" (temporary work permit) is in six weeks. In the time I lived in Paris, the Prefect always made sure I was given a récépissé before my current permit expired. I have emailed them and they replied I should stick to the dates in my convocation.

The problem is between now and then I have no valid work permit. Is this a problem for my employer? I also live in a border town and am regularly stopped by the police and immigration (douane), will I be in trouble as I have nothing but an expired permit (titre de séjour) and a letter giving me an appointment in six weeks? I am also assuming this means I cannot cross the border at all? Is there anything I can do to get out of this situation?

Comment: Whether you can travel may depend on your citizenship.  For example, if you are a US citizen, the usual 90/180 rules apply starting the day your residence permit expired.

Comment: I am a national of a country that requires a visa for practically every country in the EU.

Comment: I had a somewhat similar situation to this earlier this year.  As it was explained to me, although there was a period of time during which my work visa was expired (only about 3 weeks in my case) before my appointment at the prefecture, this was no problem *for work purposes* as long as I had the upcoming appointment.  The law has some allowance built into it for this, as it's not on you if they can't give you an appointment sooner.  That said, I was also advised not to travel outside the country in the meantime. Since you live at the border that might be tricky.

Comment: You might see if you can at least get some kind of proof that you at least have the appointment (for example, I had an e-mail notification about it from my prefecture).  Have that printed out and ready to present with your documents.

Comment: Thanks, I suppose at the end of the day there is nothing I can do but wait and make sure to keep the appointment letter with me at all times. I've also heard about the TDS being valid three months after it expired but only law I could find applies to titres for longer than 1 yr. Mine was valid for precisely 364 days. https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCodeArticle.do;jsessionid=C059BF9D1DC5F15DC548DCA6DA9A610E.tpdila19v_2?idArticle=LEGIARTI000030957659&cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006070158&categorieLien=id&dateTexte= Driving school has cancelled exam which was scheduled for this week. Life goes on.

Comment: That seems quite unfortunate. In Germany even if your residence permit is still in processing, it seems that the local Bürgeramt will still be able to produce a temporary document affirming your identity. Not sure if there is similar things in France though or if that applies to work permit as well.